# Websphere installation and JDBC configuration update using Puppet

Tags: websphere, puppet

I am trying to install WebSphere using Puppet Configuration Management. I have installed the module "puppet module install joshbeard-websphere" and started working on the same.

I am facing 2 issues:

1. After the "websphere::profile::dmgr" runs successfully I still don't get the SOAP port. It is mentioned that after successful run on client:

   When a DMGR profile is created, this module will use Puppet's exported resources to export a file resource that contains information needed for application servers to federate with it. This includes the SOAP port and the host name (fqdn).

   Is there something I am missing?
2. This module supports creating JDBC providers and data sources. At this time, it does not support the removal of JDBC providers or datasources or changing their configuration after they're created.

Comment: A few checks on the WebSphere side: 1) You need the Network Deployment edition of WAS to create a Deployment Manager profile. 2) Internally, WebSphere uses the `manageprofiles` tool to create/delete profiles. You can check the manageprofiles logs to see if the profile was created correctly. 3) To modify JDBC providers and data sources after they have been created, you can check out the `wsadmin` tool.